# A c++ function that periodically gets called

Tags: c++, function

In my c++ program I want to make a function that gets called periodically, like once every second. How can I do that?

I am creating a shell in OSX. It should also work the same in Linux. The purpose of this function is to watch spawned programs, and terminate them when they start using too much memory or cpu time.

Comment: Can you provide more context in your question? Like is this a command-line program, or is it a GUI program? Is the program required to respond to user events (e.g. keyboard events)? What operating system are you targeting? Why do you need to call a function periodically? What task is it for?

Comment: The function is not the problem. Every function can be called periodically. You need something like a thread that calls the function in a given interval.

Comment: It would certainly help to know what platform you are doing this on. E.g., on a Unix-like system, you could put your function in the handler for `SIGALRM` and request alarm signals. I'm sure similar options exist on Windows.

Comment: What about setting up a cron job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok--here's a pthread solution. Someone may want to check my pthread API usage for correctness, but I verified this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define false (0!=0)
static void * TimerRoutine(void *) ;

int main( int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    pthread_t thread ;
    pthread_attr_t attr ;

    pthread_attr_init( & attr ) ;
    pthread_create( & thread, & attr, TimerRoutine, NULL ) ;

    int done = false ;
    while( !done )
    {
        char input[80] ;
        scanf("%79s", input) ;
        // handle input command (or something)

        done = ( 0 == strcmp( input, "quit" ) ) ;
    }

    // wait for timer thread to exit
    pthread_cancel( thread ) ;
    pthread_join( thread, NULL ) ;
}

static void * TimerRoutine(void * arg)
{
    pthread_detach( pthread_self() ) ;

    int done = false ;
    while( !done )
    {
        // do background task, i.e.:
        printf("tick!\n") ;
        sleep(1) ;

        pthread_testcancel( ) ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Note if you want precise 1Hz timing the sleep(1) will need to be changed to a usleep(1000000-delta), where delta is the elapsed time since the end of the previous sleep.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Boost, You can use the Boost Timer functionality for registering callbacks which get periodically called.
Have a look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html):

You could also use timer functionality provided by each platform, but that would be non portable. Besides you havent mentioned any specific platfrom either.

EDIT: Since you are using Mac OS X, perhaps you can use [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glutTimerFunc.3.html)
      I havent used it though, just a quick google search shows that & dont this it will   work for Linux because it must be platform specific.

Answer (score 3):

You can use posix threads (`<pthread.h>`) and sleep/clock_nanosleep (`<time.h>`). POSIX API is supported by all unixes including Linux and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a high priority thread that loops but spends a second asleep in between each loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need multiple threads, what about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define false (0!=0)

int main( int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    int done = false ;
    while( !done )
    {
        // check for rogue processes here

        sleep(1) ;
        printf("tick!\n") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is used, then how can the program do anything else?

Comment: it can't--didn't know you wanted that :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Asio](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) has [timers](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/timers.html).